# Redux-toolkit payload don't reconigze type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'am using redux-toolkit in my project and i got this problem

I create this reducer:

```
setWaypointToEdit: (state, action: PayloadAction<WaypointToEditPayload>) => {

  let gridPolygonsData: GridPolygonsData;
  const { currentArea } = state.areas;      
  
  gridPolygonsData = {
    ...state.areas.gridPolygonsData,
  };

  gridPolygonsData[currentArea] = {
    ...gridPolygonsData[currentArea],
    waypointToEdit: action.payload.waypoint,
  };
  
 state = {
    ...state,
    areas: {
      ...state.areas,
      gridPolygonsData,
    },
 }

},
```

With this payload:

```
export interface WaypointToEditPayload {

 waypoint: Waypoint | RequiredWaypoint | null;

}
```

But i got an error when i try to dispatch this method:

```
setWaypointToEdit(this.getWaypoint(areaNumber, waypointId))
```

[image]

This is what the above method do

```
private getWaypoint(areaNumber: number, waypointId: number) {
const {

    areas: { gridPolygonsData }

} = useAppSelector((state) => state.project); 
const waypoints = gridPolygonsData[areaNumber].gridWaypoints;
if (waypoints)
  return waypoints.find((waypoint) => waypoint.id === waypointId) ?? null;
return null;
```

}

Even returning two types: Waypoint or null, a still got this error.
does anyone could help me? Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer expects an object. Either send the waypoint in an object with property waypoint:

```
setWaypointToEdit({ waypoint: this.getWaypoint(areaNumber, waypointId) })
```

Or change the expected type:

```
export type WaypointToEditPayload = Waypoint | RequiredWaypoint | null;
```

In which case you will need to change this part of the reducer:

```
gridPolygonsData[currentArea] = {
  ...gridPolygonsData[currentArea],
  waypointToEdit: action.payload,  // change
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You define the interface as the following.

```
export interface WaypointToEditPayload {
 waypoint: Waypoint | RequiredWaypoint | null;
}
```

So the reducer can accept `{waypoint: Waypoint | RequiredWaypoint | null}`, but your `getWaypoint` function possibly return just `null` instead of `{waypoint: null}`.

You just fix the function returning `{waypoint: null}` when it needs to return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers, your current reducer does nothing. Reassigning the `state` variable doesn't *change* the object that was in `state`. It throws away the old object, but doesn't modify it, so the change will not reflect in any way.

You have two choices here:

Use return instead of `state =`

```js
setWaypointToEdit: (state, action: PayloadAction<WaypointToEditPayload>) => {

  let gridPolygonsData: GridPolygonsData;
  const { currentArea } = state.areas;      
  
  gridPolygonsData = {
    ...state.areas.gridPolygonsData,
  };

  gridPolygonsData[currentArea] = {
    ...gridPolygonsData[currentArea],
    waypointToEdit: action.payload.waypoint,
  };
  
 return {
    ...state,
    areas: {
      ...state.areas,
      gridPolygonsData,
    },
 }

},
```

Or just modify the object (in Redux Toolkit, this is the preferred approach):

```js
setWaypointToEdit: (state, action: PayloadAction<WaypointToEditPayload>) => {
  state.areas.gridPolygonsData[state.areas.currentArea].waypointToEdit = action.payload.waypoint
}
```